# strptime returns NA values when iterating through a loop

Tags: r, format, strptime

I'm iterating through a directory of 16 .csv files and comparing it to another file (df1) using the following code:

```
d1 <- read.csv(file.choose("C:/Me/MyFileLocation))
df1 <- as.data.frame(d1)
# this is where I use strptime for df1

files <- Sys.glob("*.csv")
for (i in files) {
  df2 <- as.data.frame(read.csv(i, header = FALSE))
  # this is where I use strptime for df2
```

All the files contain a column entitled "Time" that have dates, but `df1` and `df2` have different date formats, so I used `format(strptime())` to get them into the same (and more comparable) format.

`df1$Time` is in format `"5/29/2018 4:20:00 PM"`

`df2$Time` is in format `"5/29/2018 4:20 PM"`.

This is the code I used to format them identically:

```
  df1$Time <- format(strptime(df1$Time, "%m/%d/%Y  %I:%M:%S %p"), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
  df2$Time <- format(strptime(df2$Time, "%m/%d/%Y  %I:%M %p"), format= "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

When I run my code, `df2` always returns NA values for the entire `Time` column, so I can't merge the two data frames by `Time`. I don't think this is a formatting issue because I made a separate script where I manually entered some dates from `df2` and used the same `format(strptime())` function and got successful returns. So I think that, for whatever reason, this doesn't work within the loop. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it? Converting the `Time` columns to class character didn't help either.

Comment: Maybe the error is here, `df2 <- as.data.frame(read.csv(i, header = FALSE))` you set the headers to false, unless you re-assign names to the data frame, `df2$Time` is not calling anything.

Comment: All of the columns are titled correctly! I just didn't include that portion of the code.

Comment: Are you creating the input .csv files with excel?

Comment: Yes they are created with excel

Comment: Ah, excel likes to mess up date-time in .csv. Try going to the input file and setting the format of the Time column to "mm/dd/YYYY HH:MM" and then saving. Once saved exit excel, and say no when it asks you again to save your changes. You basically need to make sure excel is feeding in the same format as your program wants.